# Refresh data sources in shared Excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use a database connection in a shared Excel workbook. How can I refresh the data source connection? Normally I would go to `data` > `connections` > `refresh all`, but this option is greyed out in a shared workbook.

I have tried to use `Workbook.RefreshAll` in a macro, but this gives an error in a shared workbook.

Comment: probably you don't have the necessary permission to do that. If you can't do that manually, then neither you can do it by a macro.

Answer (score 0):

Don't share workbooks on a network drive.  That is a horrible idea.  It will eventually, and probably quickly, corrupt your workbook and you will lose all your work.  Use Access, and split it so each user has a front end.